# Sort Desktop Icons with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, context-menu

I have setup PowerShell script that will install lots of applications onto the desktop and change a bunch of settings. After it is finished I want to make sure all the icons it adds are consistently in the same order.

**Question:** Is there a way in PowerShell to trigger the "sort by" -> "Item Type" faction found in the context menu accessible from right clicking on the desktop?

Comment: @Destroy666: Perhaps you're right - I retracted my close vote.

Comment: You are not showing any code here. what have you tried? What have you searched for? The Desktop is just a folder on the Windows FS, just approach it that way. You can just use ***SendKeys*** on your desktop for this as well. Though SendKeys is got its issues, it's still possible with it, or make a call to User32.dll to code what you need. PS is not the best thing to use for GUI automation. AutoIT, and others are better at it.

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell, you can toggle to the desktop—making it active—and automate keystrokes to configure the desktop icon sorting based on your preferences.

This process involves the following steps:

1. Activating the desktop to ensure the correct focus.
2. Emulating the key combination <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> + <kbd>`F10`</kbd> to access the right-click context menu.
3. Pressing the letter <kbd>`o`</kbd> to open the "`Sort by`" sub-menu.
4. Sending the first letter from the string of the desired value you have assigned to the variable `$sortOrder`, and selecting the appropriate sorting option.

[image]

### PowerShell

```
## Specify the sort order parameter: Name, Size, Date Modified
$sortOrder = "Item Type";

(New-Object -ComObject shell.application).toggleDesktop();
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500;

$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500;

$WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}");
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500;

$WshShell.SendKeys("o");
$WshShell.SendKeys($sortOrder.Substring(0, 1));
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Use PowerShell to Display the Desktop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-display-the-desktop/)
- [Scriptable Shell Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/scriptable-shell-objects-roadmap)
- [SendKeys Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)
- [WshShell.SendKeys](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)
- [Substring()](https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html)